# module.exports in closures

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var object = {}; // Global Object

(function() {

    var theArg, google, yahoo;

    object.google = function(arg) {
        theArg = arg;
        alert(theArg);
    }

    object.yahoo = function() {
        alert(theArg);
    }

    module.exports = yahoo;

})();

// This will set initial value of 
google("Hello World");
```

Can i call something like this `module.exports = yahoo`; and calling the `yahoo` function else where.

Comment: I don't understand this. How are able to call `google`? It is a member method of `object`. `google` is out of scope by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

**test.js**

```
var object = {}; // Global Object

alert = console.log;

(function() {

    var theArg, google, yahoo;

    object.google = function(arg) {
        theArg = arg;
        alert(theArg);
    }

    object.yahoo = function() {
        alert(theArg);
    }

    module.exports.yahoo = object.yahoo;

})();

// This will set initial value of 
object.google("Hello World");
```

**main.js**

```
require('./test.js').yahoo(); // Hello World
```

Comment: But when i call object.yahoo i don't get the alert.

Comment: Where you call it? In this file or different one in which you require the this?

Comment: I am calling from different file.

Comment: If you use alert directly you'll get error for the missing function. Use `console.log` instead